# List all unpaid invoices through stripe invoice API using PHP

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

I am trying to build a function so when user specify `date1` and `date2`, it will display all the unpaid invoices that was generated between `date1` and `date2`. I could make it work through stripe invoice API using PHP. 1) the invoice API to list all invoices does seem to have the option for you to specify "unpaid" status, plus, when I try to list all invoices within certain date range by the following code:

```
$allInvoice = \Stripe\Invoice::all(array("limit" => 100, "date[lt]" => $todate,   "date[gt]" => $startdate));
if $startdate = 2016-09-25 and $todate = 2016-09-30,
```

I only shows a few invoices on 09-30, but I have a lot more on 09-30 and even more from day 09-25 to 09-29, stripe just don't show them? any idea?